# The common way to work with transactions in C#

Tags: c#, database

How are you using transactions in your code?

The old good way was to do something like that:

```
try
{
    IDbTransaction tx = Connection.BeginTransaction();
    perform_work1
    perform_work2
    perform_work3
    tx.Commit();

}
catch(DbException)
{
   tx.Rollback();
   throw;
}
```

But then you realise that you want to add DbExceptin logging to your software, and should, replace any appearance of transaction related code.

The first idea is to make somethig similar to this:

```
public static class SafeCallerProxy
    {
        public delegate T ResultativeAction<T>();

        public static T ExecuteWithResult<T>(IDbConnection conn, ResultativeAction<T> action)
        {
            using(IDbTransaction tx = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    T result = action();
                    tx.Commit();
                    return result;
                }
                catch (System.Data.DataException)
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ExecuteAction(IDbConnection conn, Action action)
        {
            using (IDbTransaction tx = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch (System.Data.DataException)
                {
                    tx.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

usage

```
SafeCallerProxy.ExecuteAction(connection, () => 
{
  DoWork1();
  DoWork2();
  DoWork3();
}
);
```

And I think that I am reinventing bycicle here.
Please give an example of good code which incapsulates transaction mechanism,

Sory for my English.

Comment: This is actually very similar to how I have solved this problem in the past.

Comment: Why not just log the DataException when you roll back the transactions?

Comment: Just FYI, there is already a `Func<TResult>` delegate in .NET 3.0 that has the same definition as your `ResultativeAction<T>` delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use [NHibernate with Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-P3/reference/html/transaction.html) which has [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) support so I am basically defining in an external configuration file which are the methods which I would like to be executed under a SQL transaction. Those would normally be my service methods which in term might call multiple data access methods that I would like to run in a single transaction.

I consider that transaction management is a crosscutting concern and shouldn't be mixed with the data access code as it pollutes it. Spring.NET takes care of generating runtime proxies and injects the proper transaction handling code.

Comment: Thank you, I should really consider one simple pattern: when you want to add something simmilar to decorator pettern to the method, there is a great chance that you really want to simulate AOP.

Answer (score 1):

I use LINQ to Entities, which handles the transactions for me. I imagine it would be pretty easy to add automatic logging using a T4 template.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, I think that you can assume that a transaction object implementing the `IDbTransaction` interface will perform a rollback if it is disposed prior to calling the `Commit` method.  Granted, that is not a guarantee, but I think it would be a poor implementation if not implemented that way.

Given that, I would write your example simply as the following:

```
        using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            DoWork1();
            DoWork2();
            DoWork3();
            tx.Commit();
        }
```

if I needed to catch and log database exceptions, then I would wrap the entire using block in a try/catch:

```
        try
        {
            using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                DoWork1();
                DoWork2();
                DoWork3();
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            // log ex
        }
```